# Converting Name-Value table to another table with names as column headers but one name type can have multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a following Table structure:

**Structure-1**

```
+------------+-------------+---------+
| SymbolCode | CategoryId  | ItemId  |
+------------+-------------+---------+
|     212374 |        Cat1 |       1 |
|     212374 |        Cat2 |       6 |
|     212374 |        Cat3 |       5 |
|     212374 |        Cat3 |      50 |
+------------+-------------+---------+
```

I would like to convert this structure into the following:

**IntermidiateStructure**

```
+------------+------+------+------+
| SymbolCode | Cat1 | Cat2 | Cat3 |
+------------+------+------+------+
|     212374 |    1 |    6 |  5   |
|     212374 |    1 |    6 |  50  |
+------------+------+------+------+
```

I have tried using PIVOT/CrossTab but I can't use aggregate functions because there is nothing to aggregate here. I have also tried `CASE` expression but I don't want 4 rows with null's appearing in the `Cat1`, `Cat2` & `Cat3` columns where they don't have any values. And if I use an aggregate function with `CASE` then I only get one value for `CAT3` column.

I think the solution structure I am using perhaps is not accurate as it is an intermediate result for a query I am trying to build.

I have another **Structure-2** which I need to join to **Structure-1** given below:

```
+-------+------------+--------+
| Rule  | CategoryId | ItemId |
+-------+------------+--------+
| Rule1 | Cat1       |      1 |
| Rule1 | Cat2       |      6 |
| Rule2 | Cat1       |      1 |
| Rule2 | Cat2       |      6 |
| Rule2 | Cat3       |      5 |
| Rule2 | Cat3       |     50 |
+-------+------------+--------+
```

Thus if I look at the `Rule1` and `Rule2` then only `Rule2` should be applicable on SymbolCode 212374 as it matches the exact criteria, nothing more nothing less.

What sort of query I can build to do this?

Comment: Why do you need the `Cat11`, `Cat2` values repeated in the second row?  Why not just use null?

Comment: What if there were more than one ItemId for Cat1 or Cat2?

Comment: we can take either max or min why values are repeating @darsin

Comment: @TabAlleman I agree with your point, but this is a very specific case i am dealing with. With the case you have pointed out, i think the solution structure i have provided will fail.

Comment: @Darsin You haven't explained why you need to repeat the values for Cat1 or Cat2? Will you only ever have 2 values of `Cat3`?

Comment: @bluefeet The intermediate structure which you are referring to looks like the wrong approach to take. I have edited the question to show what i was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use an aggregate function to pivot the data, you'll just need something to be unique to allow for multiple rows to be returned.  For your situation, I'd use a windowing function like `row_number()`.  This will create a unique sequence for each `SymbolCode`, `CategoryID` - this number will then be used when grouping for the aggregation.

You'll start with a query similar to:

```
select  
  s1.SymbolCode,
  s1.CategoryID,
  s2.ItemId,
  seq = row_number() over(partition by s1.symbolcode, s1.categoryid 
                          order by s1.itemid)
from Structure1 s1
inner join Structure2 s2
  on s1.categoryid = s2.categoryid
  and s1.ItemId = s2.ItemId
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e7b89/4). This give a result of:

```
| SYMBOLCODE | CATEGORYID | ITEMID | SEQ |
|------------|------------|--------|-----|
|     212374 |       Cat1 |      1 |   1 |
|     212374 |       Cat1 |      1 |   2 |
|     212374 |       Cat2 |      6 |   1 |
|     212374 |       Cat2 |      6 |   2 |
|     212374 |       Cat3 |      5 |   1 |
|     212374 |       Cat3 |     50 |   2 |
```

Now you have a `seq` column that contains a unique number for each set of `SymbolCode`, `CategoryId`. Once you have this value, then you can pivot the data into columns:

```
select SymbolCode,
  Cat1 = max(case when categoryid = 'Cat1' then itemid end),
  Cat2 = max(case when categoryid = 'Cat2' then itemid end),
  Cat3 = max(case when categoryid = 'Cat3' then itemid end)
from
(
  select  
    s1.SymbolCode,
    s1.CategoryID,
    s2.ItemId,
    seq = row_number() over(partition by s1.symbolcode, s1.categoryid 
                            order by s1.itemid)
  from Structure1 s1
  inner join Structure2 s2
    on s1.categoryid = s2.categoryid
    and s1.ItemId = s2.ItemId
) d
group by symbolcode, seq;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e7b89/5). This gives a final result of:

```
| SYMBOLCODE | CAT1 | CAT2 | CAT3 |
|------------|------|------|------|
|     212374 |    1 |    6 |    5 |
|     212374 |    1 |    6 |   50 |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table (symbolcode int,category varchar(10),itemid int)
insert into @t (symbolcode,category,itemid)values (212374,'cat1',1)
insert into @t (symbolcode,category,itemid)values (212374,'cat2',6)
insert into @t (symbolcode,category,itemid)values (212374,'cat3',5)
insert into @t (symbolcode,category,itemid)values (212374,'cat3',60)

;WITH CTE AS(
select symbolcode,cat1,cat2,cat3
from
(
  select symbolcode, category,itemid
  from @t
) d
pivot
(
  max(itemid)
  for category in (cat1,cat2,cat3)
) piv
)
,CTE2 AS
(select symbolcode,cat1,cat2,cat3
from
(
  select symbolcode, category,itemid
  from @t
) d
pivot
(
  MIN(itemid)
  for category in (cat1,cat2,cat3)
) piv)

select * from CTE
UNION 
select * from CTE2
```

Comment: @darsin can you please check the updated query as it modified according to your required data

Answer (score -1):

Well for this very specific case, you could do this:

```
SELECT
  SymbolCode
, (SELECT TOP 1 ItemId FROM MyTable WHERE CategoryId='Cat1' AND SymbolCode=mt.SymbolCode) AS Cat1
, (SELECT TOP 1 ItemId FROM MyTable WHERE CategoryId='Cat2' AND SymbolCode=mt.SymbolCode) AS Cat2
, ItemId AS Cat3
FROM MyTable mt
WHERE CategoryId='Cat3'
```